# export const variable undefined on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have defined some const on Color.js, but some of the Color is undefined when i call it on Screen.js

I use react-native 0.45 for this project. Here's the code i wrote :

Color.js

```
export const ATHENS_GRAY = '#EDEEF0';
export const AQUA_SPRING = '#F8FBFD';
export const BLACK = '#000000';
export const BRIGHT_TURQUOISE = '#1BC1F1';
export const CATSKILL_WHITE = '#E4ECF4';
export const FROLY = '#F68181';
export const FUN_BLUE = '#1B61AD';
export const HIT_GRAY = '#A3AEB9';
export const JUMBO = '#7C7D80';
export const LIMED_SPRUCE = '#3D474C';
```

Screen.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Color from './Color';

export default class Screen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(Color.BRIGHT_TURQUOISE);
    console.log(Color.FUN_BLUE);
  }

  render() {
    return (<View/>)
  }
}
```

The result of the console.log :

> Color.BRIGHT_TURQUOISE is undefined
>
> Color.FUN_BLUE is '#1B61AD'

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong, maybe a typo? :(

Comment: it's like there is a cache, because when i change the FUN_BLUE variable on the Color.js, like export const FUN_BLUE = '#FFFFFF'; the value is still #1B61AD, i run my application on iOS simulator, and i have press Command+r to refresh my simulator

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d

Answer (score 2):

I have try it on my terminal using `react-native log-android` , 
and both values ​​are obtained like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2hV8.png)

Or maybe you can try another way to export your constant on your `Color.js` like this :

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
   ATHENS_GRAY : '#EDEEF0',
   AQUA_SPRING : '#F8FBFD',
   BLACK : '#000000',
   BRIGHT_TURQUOISE : '#1BC1F1',
   CATSKILL_WHITE : '#E4ECF4',
   FROLY : '#F68181',
   FUN_BLUE : '#1B61AD',
   HIT_GRAY : '#A3AEB9',
   JUMBO : '#7C7D80',
   LIMED_SPRUCE : '#3D474C',
});
```

And you can try again :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is on my iOS simulator, it keeps the cache

Comment: you have tried to reload your apps? or maybe you need to stop your server and start again.

Comment: i have pressed Command+R, restart my computer, clean my project, restart the server, but the problem is the same

Comment: The undefined variable occurred only on the last variable i added

Comment: i have tried another way to export constant on your Color.js, please try again Mr Robi, and give me how about the result, still same or no?

Comment: it's working fine with your solution srsugara. thank you very much